# На чем лучше определять тип устройства (php- или js-библиотека)?

Tags: php, javascript

Есть следующая задача: определять тип устройства и на мобильных подключать стили и скрипты, отличные от десктопных. Если использовать js-библиотеку, то определит ли она устройство раньше, чем загрузятся стили и скрипты? Или здесь лучше использовать PHP?

Comment: А может лучше `@media` запросы заюзать?

Comment: Тут дело не в адаптивности. Сайт адаптивный, но моб. версия выполнена, как приложение, совершенно отлична от десктопа. Поэтому именно для моб. устройств (не планшетов и не компов), нужно подключать отдельные стили и скрипты.

Comment: Кажись, вы, заблуждаетесь, адаптивный, но приложение. Так и пишите приложение или возьмите какой-нибудь `WebViwer`. да и вообще, можно адаптировать так, что до неузнаваемости и будет как приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Определение устройств через `PHP` подходит для создания полноценной мобильной версии так как на этапе ответа сервера мы можем отдавать браузеру облегченный контент и подходящие шаблоны.

В таком случае можно использовать библиотеку [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/)

Если вам нужен просто адаптивный сайт, то подключать нужные `css`-правила можно через `@media`. Определять ширину экрана через `js` используя, например, `window.innerWidth()` и подключать нужные скрипты.

Вариантов много.

Comment: Ширина экрана не подходит. Нужно менять стили и скрипты именно для мобильных телефонов, независимо от разрешения. Ведь в портретной ориентации ширина может быть как у планшета.

Comment: Лучше это предоставить серверу и пусть он отдаёт и скрипты и вьюхи для надлежащего типа устройства.